# How to create Horizontal Scrollable dayView

Tags: android, seekbar, android-calendar, scrollable

In my project, I need to create a horizontal Scrollable dayView. Meetings will be scheduled say like 1PM-2 PM, If user needs, he can increase or decrease the timings say by 10 mins or 5 mins. When user will swipe dayview should scroll ... like previous date or next date. If user touch only, a head should appear and then user can reschedule the timings by dragging the head as we do in seek bar. This should be done for every meeting in the day.

[image]

Help me to solve this thing.

Thanks

Comment: did you find solution for this? can you share?

Comment: I made it using Canvas

Comment: Could you share the code here?

Comment: @Amarnath I can't share my code due to NDA but I can guide you. Take a look on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm8Zt1ps9P8) and this project is hosted [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-timeline/).. This was big help for me. For booking slot you can handle things in onTouchEvent()  using co-ordinates :) Write me if any further doubt :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, i will try to customise this. many thanks.

Comment: @Amarnath Do upvote the question.. Possible someone suggest better solution :)